# Add UNNotificationAction on some particular notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to add UNNotificationAction in my application on push notification which i have done with following code:-

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        UNNotificationAction *accept = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:kAcceptIdentifier
                                                                        title:NSLocalizedString(@"Accept", nil)
                                                                      options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
        UNNotificationAction *reject = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:kRejectIdentifier
                                                                            title:NSLocalizedString(@"Reject", nil)
                                                                          options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
        NSArray *buttons = @[ accept, reject ];

        // create a category for message failed
        UNNotificationCategory *buttonsAction = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"Chat_Request"
                                                                                       actions:buttons
                                                                             intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                                                                options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
        NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:buttonsAction, nil];

        // registration
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories:categories];
    }];
```

But now I want these actions to appear on some particular push notifications received from server. Currently it is showing on all notifications. I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself with following code:

```
[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
    | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        UNNotificationAction *accept = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:kAcceptIdentifier
                                                                        title:NSLocalizedString(@"Accept", nil)
                                                                      options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
        UNNotificationAction *reject = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:kRejectIdentifier
                                                                            title:NSLocalizedString(@"Reject", nil)
                                                                          options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
        NSArray *buttons = @[ accept, reject ];

        // create a category for action
        UNNotificationCategory *buttonsAction = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"Chat_Request"
                                                                                       actions:buttons
                                                                             intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                                                                options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
        NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:buttonsAction, nil];

        // registration
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories:categories];
    }];
```

Make sure your payload must contain "category" key with same identifier as yours in your code. For example:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Testing2","badge":1,"sound":"default","category":"Chat_Request"}}
```